# Dynamically populate dropdown list based on previous field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

I am using AngularJS to create a form with several dropdown list. I want to easily define this logic:

If dropdown *n* selected item *x*, other dropdown below (one or more) will be populated with *y* data

... and so on

For example, assume a=[1,2,3]
1. If a=1 is selected, b will be [8,9]
2. If a=2 is selected, b will be [0,2]

...

I think you get the idea. I am thinking of three options:

**Option 1:**
I could do this with AngularJS with bind the value of dropdown and do a huge nested `if` statement. But this doesn't look elegant.

**Option 2:**

I could define the relationship in such a way:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [
  {
    a:1,
    value: [8,9]
  }, {
    a:2,
    value: [0,2]
  }
]
```

**Option 3:**

Or I could do the nested objects. But then how to handle nested JSON in form model?? Plus if I want to change the hierarchy is a little tough? I rather have it flat.

```
a = [
  {
    value: 1,
    b: [8,9]
  }, {
    value: 2,
    b: [0,2]
  }, {
    value: 3,
    b: []
  }
]
```

What is the most awesome and elegant way to do something like this? Is there even a library / module?

Comment: Probably get the second field's values via a method on your Controller: `<option ng-repeat="b in ctrl.getBValues(aValue)">{{b}} </option>`. That'll give you a lot of flexibility, anyway.

Comment: Look at `ng-if`, `ng-switch` and Angular has `ternary operators` within ng-class etc.

Comment: @EmilLundberg Can you explain where `aValue` is coming from? @Dylan: I am not looking to show or hide things. It's the model behind each dropdown that needs to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with option 2.

A select element has a key and a display value for its options (key,displayValue).

Example:

```
<select>
    <option value="key">displayValue</option>
<select>
```

ng-options accepts an expression following this format:

```
ng-options="item.key as item.value for item in items"
```

This specifies that key will be bound to item.key and value will be bound to item.value when the options are rendered.

You could also bind the entire item as the key:

```
ng-options="item as item.value for item in items"
```

Depending on what key you provide, the ng-model will be bound to it when an option is selected.

**Controller**

```
    var app = angular.module("app", []);
    app.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope) {
        var b = [
          {
              a: 1,
              value: [8, 9]
          }, {
              a: 2,
              value: [0, 2]
          }
        ];
        $scope.b = b;
    });
```

**HTML**

```
    <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
        <select ng-model="first" ng-options="bb as bb.a for bb in b"></select> {{first}}<br />
        <select ng-model="second" ng-options="cc as cc for cc in first.value"></select>{{second}}
    </body>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g4CHv/1/)

Comment: Can you explain the usage of `as` and `for`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the ng-change directive and call a function loadCombo2(valueCombo1) in order to load your second combo box with your restriction from the first combo box.

And in this function set the data of the second combo box to : valueCombo1.b (from the Option 3)

Comment: This would be not much different from nested `if`

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
$scope.a = [1,2,3];

$scope.b = {
    1 : [1,2],
    2 : [2,4],
    3 : [3,6]
};
```

View

```
<select 
    ng-options="item for item in a"
    ng-model="firstSelection">
</select>

<!-- use firstSelection to populate the second dropdown -->
<select
    ng-options="item for item in b[firstSelection]"
    ng-model="secondSelection">
</select>
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KvJA2/)**